# AngularDart browser compatibility

Tags: dart, compatibility, angular-dart, browser-support

What versions of browsers are supported by current version (0.13) of AngularDart? Especially interested in Internet Explorer 9 support. 
Is there some known future plans about that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seems that there no information about browser support yet, but AngularDart developers are going to publish this info as soon as possible: 
https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/1286

Answer (score 3):

I believe that will not happen.  Even Microsoft announced a few days ago that versions before IE11 would not be supported.

Edit: from http://news.dartlang.org/2014/05/dart-support-for-internet-explorer.html:

> Dart v1.5, scheduled for late June, will be the last Dart release to
>   support Internet Explorer 9. Dart will continue to support the latest
>   releases of Firefox, Chrome, and Safari, as well as the two most
>   recent releases of Internet Explorer – currently IE10 & IE11.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I've asked not about Dart itself, but about AngularDart. For example, PolymerDart is written in Dart 1.5 but doesn't support IE9, despite Dart 1.5 does.